# Получение всех id разделов инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

Как в типе инфоблока site_content выбрать все айдишники разделов?

```
$arSelect = Array("ID");
$arOrder = Array("SORT"=>"ASC"); 
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_TYPE"=>"site_content");
$res = CIBlockSection::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->Fetch())
{
    echo $ob["ID"])."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была: `echo $ob["ID"])."<br>";` лишнее закрытие скобки.

Рабочий код:

```
if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")){
    $arSelect = Array("ID");
    $arOrder = Array("SORT"=>"ASC"); 
    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_TYPE"=>"site_content");
    $res = CIBlockSection::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, $arSelect);
    while($ob = $res->Fetch())
        echo $ob["ID"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: я с вами не совсем согласен так как мне нужно у типа инфоблока site_content выбрать именно все айдишники  разделов, поэтому данный вариант не подходит. Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: @ChromeChrome Внёс правки

Comment: @ChromeChrome поправил. В `CIBlockSection::GetList` `$arSelect` 4 параметр

Comment: @ChromeChrome Помогло?

Comment: странно конешчо, но почему то не все выводятся((

Comment: @ChromeChrome — я тестирую у себя и всё работает как надо

Comment: спасибо @Mihanik71